# Automate writing azure resource keys/connection strings to Key Vault using bicep or related approach

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

So currently we are writing resources to Azure using bicep and that process is working well.

However the task of getting database connection strings or other credentials into Key Vault is a manual process that is prone to an inevitable mistake at some point.

What we'd like to be doing is have a automated process for getting those conn strs' etc into the vault.

I've seen this approach:

```
resource storageAccountConnectionString 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2019-09-01' = {
  name: '${connectionStringSecretName[0].name}'
  properties: {
    value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storage_Accounts[0]};AccountKey=${listKeys('${storage_Accounts[0].id}', '${storage_Accounts[0].apiVersion}').keys[0].value};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage}'
  }
}
```

but that is going to result in a plain text version of the string living somewhere during the deployment process.

I've seen no obvious way of doing this but have to assume it is possible. Am guessing maybe there is an approach using some other Azure feature to achieve this but am coming up short. I'd have thought this was a much used approach so am hoping someone can shed some light or at least offer some sign posts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The approach you are describing won't let any plain text secret in your deployment process

Comment: @Thomas can you elaborate please?

Comment: If you dont use it as an output of your template it wont be exposed, it wont be stored in the deployment history: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#valid-uses

Comment: You can also use Azure managed identity among the resources to avoid providing your keys like that. If enabled managed identity takes care of the connections between resources and can be configured by azure bicep.

Comment: Ali Khan do you have a relevant link please?

Comment: For code simplicity you can also call `storageAccounts[0].listKeys()`